# Matrix not spacing properly with subscripts

Tags: spacing, matrices

In this matrix with subscripts the braces are not ''containing'' the entires, how can I fix it?

[image]

This is what I hope to do

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        S_{11} &\cdots & S_{1(i-1)} \\
        \vdots &        & \vdots \\
        S_{(i-1)1}   & \cdots & S_{(i-1)(i-1)} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: you could use `\left[\begin{matrix}...` but your image  looks fine to me the [] do not need to be any bigger.

Comment: Normally latex/amsmath goes to some effort not to do what you ask as it is distracting if the size of brackets on nearby matrices changes just because of subscripts, but if you want that, the code in my first comment will do it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Somehow on my side this (and Fernando's method below) produces the same effect as bmatrix

Comment: it depends on your font and your settings of `\delimiershortfall` but as you have shown no relevent example,  people will assume the default settings. Questions should always include a complete example that shows the problem.  Here though there really is no problem, the output you show is by design.

Comment: You can increase `\arraystretch`, but that will also increase the row spacing.  You can add struts to the beginning and end, but they will have to be larger than `\mathstrut`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adds struts to the matrix.  There is a sudden increase in size between 1.3 and 1.4.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        S_{11} &\cdots & S_{1(i-1)} \\
        \vdots &        & \vdots \\
        S_{(i-1)1}   & \cdots & S_{(i-1)(i-1)}
    \end{bmatrix}
  =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \rule{0pt}{1.4\ht\strutbox}
        S_{11} &\cdots & S_{1(i-1)} \\
        \vdots &        & \vdots \\
        S_{(i-1)1}   & \cdots & S_{(i-1)(i-1)} 
      \rule[-1.4\dp\strutbox]{0pt}{0pt}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, finally worked!!

Answer (score 1):

As David said, you can use `\left[\begin{matrix}` if you want your own delimiters for the matrix, but this still does not provide the proper spacing, to get what you want you'll need to use some sort of horizontal spacing, in this case I think `\` is fine, although you can choose for yourself:

```
\left[\
\begin{matrix} 
        S_{11} &\cdots & S_{1(i-1)} \\
        \vdots &        & \vdots \\
        S_{(i-1)1}   & \cdots & S_{(i-1)(i-1)} \\
\end{matrix}\ \right]
```

Result:

[image]